# I can not remove a directory in a docker container

Tags: linux, git, docker, containers

i have a container generated from an image, and that image was generated by another container

The container that the image was based there two directories, one of these directories i created with mkdir, the other directory was created through the git clone.

But when I generate a new container from that image, **I can not delete the directory that was generated by git**, I can erase that exists within that folder, but not the root folder.
**I can delete the folder created by the mkdir.**

I do not know if there is a special feature of git to control files.

ever was something like the docker, but the issue was closed https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1672

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is the version of docker u are using? Can you share the dockerfile or image you are using??

Comment: Is the directory still in use by the container / other containers when you are trying to remove it?

Comment: @SergiuCornea No, not there anything using this directory

Comment: @Shibashis Using Docker v1.10, i can share the image at another time

Comment: @Caiota have you tried the suggestion on the Docker Git page? Adding `RUN rm -Rf /var/shared/sites/coursecal/* /var/shared/sites/coursecal/.*git` in the container Dockerfile?

Comment: @Sergiu Yes, I tried but not removed